# Makefile in multiple directories and multiple sources

Tags: c, makefile

I have a small project with the following directory structure:

```
src/
  game/
    some srcs...
  platform/
    sdl/
      main.c
      Makefile
  engine.c
  engine.h
Makefile
```

I'm planning to have multiple directories inside platform with the different platforms i'm targeting my small project. The root-level Makefile is just a helper: it allows me to, from the root folder, run things like "make platform-name", "make platform-name-clean", etc.

Here's my actual Makefile, inside the platform folder:

```
TARGET = sdl-game
SRC_FOLDER = ../..
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -DPLAT_SDL
LDFLAGS = -lm

OBJECTS = main.o \
        $(SRC_FOLDER)/engine.o \
        $(SRC_FOLDER)/game/game.o \
        $(SRC_FOLDER)/game/components.o

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(SRC_FOLDER)/*.o
    rm -rf $(SRC_FOLDER)/game/*.o
    rm -rf $(SRC_FOLDER)/platform/sdl/*.o
    rm -rf $(SRC_FOLDER)/platform/sdl/sdl
```

The problem is: i'm not able to run this from outside the platform/sdl folder with my root-level Makefile:

```
null:
make -C src/platform/sdl -f Makefile
```

Any ideas? Also, how do i move those .o objects to a "build/platform-name" folder?

Comment: Have you already tried [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)? You can place `CMakeLists.txt` in each folder with sources and include them in your root `CMakeLists.txt` via `add_subdirectory()`.

Comment: Yeah, i tried, but i prefer to keep things simple and just use make.

Comment: You say "_I'm not able to run this_".  What does that mean?  Does if fail?  What are the errors?  Does it not do the right thing?  What does it do and why is that wrong?  We can't help if you don't explain what doesn't work.

Comment: FYI, you should _never_ use `make` directly in a makefile to run another make.  You should always use the `$(MAKE)` variable.  Also, the `-f Makefile` is not needed here since make will search for `Makefile` by default.

Comment: make[1]: Entering directory `/dev/proj/src/platform/sdl'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../../engine.o', needed by `sdl.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/dev/proj/src/platform/sdl'
make: *** [sdl] Error 2

Comment: Also, how do i move those .o objects to a "build/platform-name" folder?

Comment: "Needed by *sdl*"? Not sdl-game? And `../../engine.o`, not `../../engine.c`? I'm starting to suspect that the makefile you're showing us isn't exactly the makefile you're trying to use. Anyway, you can simplify the experiment a little by skipping the "helper" makefile and doing `cd src/platform/sdl; make`.

Comment: You've just edited the makefile in the question, and the real problem is now visible. Where do you want the object files to go?

Answer (score 0):

Never call a Makefile in other directory; instead, put a Makefile in each subdirectory, and add a main Makefile in the root of your project like this :

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

DIRS = subdir1 subdir2 ...

depend all clean ::
    @ for d in $(DIRS) ; do \
        (cd $$d && make $@) ;\
    done
```

But I'm not sure to answer your question?

Comment: This ought to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Indeed, but the example couldn't fit in a comment ;-)

Comment: Since it *does* call a makefile in another directory, the example might not be worth having.

Comment: That seems to be a distinction without a difference. How is `cd foo/ && make` superior to `make -C foo/`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your comment ("build, on root"), correctly, this should do what you want:

```
...
OBJ_FOLDER = ../../../build
...

OBJECTS = $(OBJ_FOLDER)/main.o \
          $(OBJ_FOLDER)/engine.o \
          $(OBJ_FOLDER)/game.o \
          $(OBJ_FOLDER)/components.o

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

vpath %.c $(SRC_FOLDER) $(SRC_FOLDER)/game

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_FOLDER/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_FOLDER)/*.o
    rm -rf sdl
```

Comment: How do i move the object files to the build folder? Do i need a SRC_LIST with my .c files are?

Comment: @vinnylinux: This makefile will build the object files in the `build` folder.

Comment: But how does it get the C files?

Comment: @vinnylinux: By means of `vpath`. Perhaps you should ask a simpler question.